# How to deploy an Android instant app from Azure-DevOps release pipeline

Tags: android, google-play, azure-pipelines, google-play-console, android-instant-apps

I am trying to deploy an [Android Instant App](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant) using Azure DevOps release pipelines. Therefore I already have a working release pipeline for my app and can successfully publish a normal app bundle to the play store using the [Google Play extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) from Microsoft. Now I want to create an instant app experience for my app.

Ideally the same app bundle uploaded for the "normal" app release is also used for the instant app.

I did not find any resources which describe how to handle this case.

---

How do I have to setup a release job in order to deploy my app as an instant app?

Comment: Unfortunaly not. I wrote with google support but they did not understand the problem and could not help me.